# Uninstalling allegro 4.4 and installing 4.2 on ubuntu 19.10

Tags: 19.10, libraries

I installed allegro 4.4.3 with the commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install liballegro4.4 liballegro4-dev allegro4-doc
```

Can you tell me how to uninstall it please because i need the 4.2 version?

Answer (score 1):

You can completely remove allergro by executing below commands in terminal.

```
sudo apt purge allegro4.4
```

Remove its dependencies.

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Allergro 4.2 version is not available through repositories.

You can manually download source code, compile and install it.

Make sure that you have development libraries installed to compile.

```
sudo apt install build-essential

wget -c 'https://github.com/liballeg/allegro5/releases/download/v4-2-3-1/allegro-4.2.3.1.tar.gz'

tar xvf allegro-4.2.3.1.tar.gz

cd allegro-4.2.3.1/ && sudo ./configure 

sudo make && sudo make install
```

Comment: Hello @KK Patel thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: i unistalled the 4.4.3 version and i installed the 4.2 with sudo apt-get install  liballegro4.2 liballegro4.2-dev, but when i print the version, it prints 4.4.3. I used printf("Allegro version = %s\n", allegro_id);

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I need allegro 4.2 (it's a sort of imposition by my professor)

Comment: Please edit question according to it.

Comment: Hi @KKPatel thank you a lot for the improvement of your answer. I ran all your commands, and, when i run the last one the output is: makefile:421: *** recipe commences before first target. Stop.

Comment: Did you try to edit any makefile ?

Comment: I didin't do nothing, i only ran your commands...but remember that before your commands i ran sudo apt-get install liballegro4.2 liballegro4.2-dev